# Segfault with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to execute a test with mocha in node and it's stopping with a Segmentation Fault.

In the process of gathering intelligence on the problem, I noticed:

- I updated node and the modules
- I deleted node_modules and re `npm install`
- After using a bunch of `console.log` I located the problem after the `render` method returns and the `componentDidUpdate` of my react component fires
- When using iron-node there's no segfault. The test is actually passing
- With node, the segfault only occur when I run only the problematic test (with mocha's `it.only(...)`)

I'd file an issue but I don't know how to reproduce it yet.

Any idea/help would be more than welcome :)

EDIT:

For me it doesn't make any sense but if it does for you, I got that using this tool: https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler

```
PID 19289 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x38
/home/guillaume/Documents/Random_Projects/cookies/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x1a1b)[0x7fb63afb7a1b]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10f00)[0x7fb640bb1f00]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal9FieldType7AsClassEv+0x15)[0x94a515]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal9FieldType7ConvertEPNS0_4ZoneE+0x24)[0x94a674]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler17AccessInfoFactory25ComputePropertyAccessInfoENS0_6HandleINS0_3MapEEENS3_INS0_4NameEEENS1_10AccessModeEPNS1_18PropertyAccessInfoE+0x7a8)[0x75bcc8]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler17AccessInfoFactory26ComputePropertyAccessInfosERKNS0_4ListINS0_6HandleINS0_3MapEEENS0_25FreeStoreAllocationPolicyEEENS4_INS0_4NameEEENS1_10AccessModeEPNS0_10ZoneVectorINS1_18PropertyAccessInfoEEE+0xae)[0x75c34e]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler29JSNativeContextSpecialization17ReduceNamedAccessEPNS1_4NodeES4_RKNS0_4ListINS0_6HandleINS0_3MapEEENS0_25FreeStoreAllocationPolicyEEENS6_INS0_4NameEEENS1_10AccessModeENS0_12LanguageModeES4_+0x156)[0x7c5446]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler29JSNativeContextSpecialization17ReduceNamedAccessEPNS1_4NodeES4_RKNS0_13FeedbackNexusENS0_6HandleINS0_4NameEEENS1_10AccessModeENS0_12LanguageModeE+0xff)[0x7c74cf]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler29JSNativeContextSpecialization17ReduceJSLoadNamedEPNS1_4NodeE+0x7f)[0x7c755f]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler29JSNativeContextSpecialization6ReduceEPNS1_4NodeE+0x45)[0x7c9e25]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler12GraphReducer6ReduceEPNS1_4NodeE+0x36)[0x799706]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler12GraphReducer9ReduceTopEv+0x1cc)[0x79a15c]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler12GraphReducer10ReduceNodeEPNS1_4NodeE+0x68)[0x79a288]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8compiler8Pipeline12GenerateCodeEv+0xa4b)[0x7fe08b]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal19OptimizedCompileJob11CreateGraphEv+0x26c)[0x85537c]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal8Compiler16GetOptimizedCodeENS0_6HandleINS0_10JSFunctionEEENS1_15ConcurrencyModeENS0_9BailoutIdEPNS0_15JavaScriptFrameE+0xf0f)[0x856d4f]
/usr/bin/node[0xb0202a]
/usr/bin/node(_ZN2v88internal35Runtime_CompileOptimized_ConcurrentEiPPNS0_6ObjectEPNS0_7IsolateE+0xda)[0xb0269a]
[0x2cab7ce0961b]
```

EDIT 2:

I tried to extract the behavior from my test but since it's an integration/e2e test, everything is kind of linked.

So here's what I do:

Everything works as expected until I change the route of the `react-router`. Then a component render... or is supposed to. The error happens after the `render` method (and before the `componentDidUpdate` of a simple component). However, the component is rendered without problem earlier in the test... as well as when I execute it along with all the other tests...

I tried to change the render method to return `<h1>Hello</h1>` but I still run into the segfault.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I'm trying to strip it down to the minimum because posting the whole project seems a bit too much. I just have a lot of trouble since I really don't know where the problem come from. I'll post it as soon as I find a simplified way to reproduce the issue !

Comment: @MarcB I really don't have a clue how to reproduce it. I try to give more info in the last edit. Otherwise, I can give you access to the repository if you have time to take a look.

Comment: Which Node version are you using? Have you tested it with other versions? (you can easily install different versions of Node next to each other using a version manager like [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

Comment: @robertklep I just tried with nvm. It worked with all the version I tried ! Maybe the package on the ArchLinux repo had a problem !?

Comment: @Yormi hmm you might begin to think that, yes. Did you try to install the exact version that you're running on ArchLinux with nvm to see if it's not an issue with a particular version, but specifically ArchLinux's version?

Comment: Yes. I'm using node 6.3.0 on nvm and that was the version I had installed with pacman.

Comment: Usually updating Node.js to the latest LTS version will fix `SIGSEGV Segmantation fault` errors.